# Mutually exclusive probabilities

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

For my probability class, we were asked to solve a few questions about the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion:

Prove they are true, or provide a counter example.

1) If P(A)+P(B)+P(C) = 1, are A,B,C mutually exclusive?

2) If $P(A \cup B \cup C) = 1$, are these events mutually exclusive?

So, I was trying to attempt the contrapositive for both since it seemed easier. To assume (for either problem) that they are mutually exclusive would be to say that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. We can also say that $B\cap C = \emptyset$, and again for $A \cap C$. Lastly, we know that $A\cap B\cap C = \emptyset$.

This means that (based on the principle of inclusion-exclusion), $P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$.

I don't know where to go from here; I know all event-intersections are empty but am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to prove the contrapositive, you need to start by assuming they are *not* mutually exclusive.

Comment: Okay, yeah - I totally see I wasn't even thinking. Even after correcting that approach (now assuming that they are NOT mutually ex), I seem a bit lost. I know that $P(A\cup B \cup C)$ will not ONLY be $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$ but also, at least one intersection. How would I proceed from here?

Comment: @fyb805 I think instead of going for the contrapositive, you should think about possible counterexamples...

Comment: Okay - so a possible counterexample to the first problem could be something like: Consider an 8 sided die labeled 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9; A is rolling an even number, B a prime, and C a 1; all 3 are mutually exclusive. P(A) is 3/8; P(B) is 3/8; P(C) is 1/8; the sum of all 3 is 7/8; however, since they are mutually exclusive, they should sum to 1. If we consider the second problem (union), and that they are mutually exclusive, the union of the 3 is really just the sum of the 3, or 7/8; so this counter-example works for both!?

Comment: No, @fyb805 For (a) you seek an example of events $A,B,C$ where the sum of their probabilities *does* equal one, yet they are *not* mutually exclusive.  And for (b) an example where their union has probability 1 but they are not mutually exclusive.